# Reflection is not allowed on private static final int java.util.BitSet.ADDRESS_BITS_PER_WORD error

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine

While I am accessing data using Gson from GAE getting exception:

> Exception:java.lang.SecurityException:
>   java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Reflection is not allowed on private
>   static final int java.util.BitSet.ADDRESS_BITS_PER_WORD

My code is:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(dspinfo1);
JsonElement element1 = gson.toJsonTree(dspbh);
jsonObject.add("xxx", element1);
jsonObject.add("xxxx", element);
out.print(jsonObject.toString());
```

So please give me suggestion, if possible with example.
complete ex is:

```
List<DSPMaster> dpsinfo1=new ArrayList<DSPMaster>(); 
DSPMaster dspinfo1 = dspDao.getdeliveryprovider(Long.parseLong(xxxx));
response.setContentType("text/html"); 
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
Gson gson = new Gson(); JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject(); 
JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(dspinfo1);
jsonObject.add("xxxx", element); 
out.print(jsonObject.toString());
```

Comment: Your stacktrace is a bit short to make any suggestions.

Comment: What are `dspinfo1` and `dspbh`? It would really help if you'd provide a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem, as well as the complete stack trace.

Comment: dspinfo1 and dspbh are my class objects.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
Field field = MyClass.class.getField("ADDRESS_BITS_PER_WORD");
field.setAccessible(true);
```

Comment: can u elaborate more please.

Comment: You are getting a SecurityException because gson is trying to access a private field via reflection. By setting the accessible flag on the field prior to invoking gson, it's likely it will be allowed. Note: I'm not sure if GAE will let you call `Field.setAccessible(true)`, this may be disallowed by the SecurityManager

Answer (score 0):

You can try Jackson your class, convert it to json schema and later on pre-compile class. This will allow you to bypass reflection issue in GAE.