# Gson error: Reflection is not allowed on private java.lang.String java.util.regex.Pattern.pattern

Tags: java, gson

I'm using .fronJson of Gson,

```
 List<MyPattern> MyPattern = gson.fromJson(jsonReader,
         new TypeToken<List<MyPattern>>() {}.getType() );
```

but I got the error message below

> java.lang.SecurityException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Reflection is not allowed on private java.lang.String java.util.regex.Pattern.pattern
>       at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-ea4f755134111bd0(Request.java)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:197)
>       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)

Here's my class MyPattern.

```
public class MyPattern {
    public String category;
    public Pattern regex;

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setRegex(String regex) {
        this.regex = Pattern.compile(regex);
    }

    public Pattern getRegex() {
        return regex;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "key: " + this.category + ", pattern: " + this.regex;
    }
}
```

Just wondering is this error caused by Pattern.compile()? It works if I change `public Pattern regex;`
to 
`public String regex;` with

`public void setRegex(String regex) {
        this.regex = regex;
    }`. But wondering why Pattern doesn't work and it there a way to solve it and keep using Pattern.

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32993474/reflection-is-not-allowed-on-private-static-final-int-java-util-bitset-address-b

Comment: @Kevin yes I did, but I didn't find how to solve my problem.... All the fields in MyPattern class are already public.

Comment: Can you include the json that you're using as well? I tried this locally and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin! Here's my json file: [
    {
      "category":"gradle cache crash",
      "regex":"Cannot find snapshot"
    },
    {
      "category":"Build timed out",
      "regex":"timed out"
    }]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the SecurityException was thrown because of some sandbox restrictions enforced by Google App Engine (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14137943))

To get around this I would recommend the following setup:

```
public class MyPattern {
    public String category;
    public String regex;
    public Pattern pattern;

    public Pattern getPattern() {
        if(pattern == null) {
            pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        }
        return pattern;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it on Google App Engine but you'll most likely have to do something along those lines